# SSRS: page navigation for HTML reports

Tags: html, sql-server, reporting-services, navigation, report

I'm using Report Builder 3.0, SQL Server 2014 Express version, IE 11. We use HTML format for the reports. 
I'm looking for a way to add a page navigation for a report. If a report has more than one page there is a page navigation in the Report Builder 'Preview' mode, but there is no such option in a browser. 
Please advise how to add a page navigation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETOww.png)

Thanks,
Inna

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of HTML report page? As far as I know, SSRS renders rdl files as paginated reports by default.

Comment: *"there is no such option in a browser."* Yes there is. They're little blue ► and ◄ icons below the parameters pane.

Comment: rv:Toolbar=Full? Have you seen this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-parameter-reference?view=sql-server-ver15#bkmk_reportserver

Comment: ser_nicky: SSRS renders the report as paginated file, but IE doesn't display it per page. The user can not "jump" to a desired page.

Comment: Larnu, see the screenshot I posted. What browser did you mean ?

Comment: Максим Золотенко :How this article can help me with a navigation?

Comment: @user12585338 the extension you are using is MHTML, not HTML. Please check following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/rendering-behaviors-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15#general-behaviors-for-html-mhtml-word-and-excel-soft-page-break-renderers . You need to check if there are explicit page breaks inserted

Comment: ser-nicky: I'm using HTML, but for screenshot I've created MHTML. HTML behaves the same way as MHTML. I verified it.

Comment: another useful link: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3482/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-controlling-report-page-breaks/

Comment: And also check if the report renders properly in other browsers. If yes, maybe this should be solution to your problem: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3666/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-is-not-compatible-with-internet-explorer-11/

Comment: ser-nicky: I've already seen this article, it doesn't help to solve a navigation issue. How can I "jump" from page 1 to page 3 , for example? There is no such option. I have to scroll in order get a desired page. this solution is not acceptable for our customers.

Comment: Ok, I finally get what you want to achieve:)...You didn't specify that you need "jump" functionality, I thought that you can't navigate between the pages at all. I'm afraid that it isn't possible to "jump", since HTML/MHTML is an exported version of the report. Is PDF an option for you? Because if you export to PDF, you can then "jump" between the pages.